# reading files and writing the content to pd.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to panda and df concept.

I have two folders, each folder has number of files. I want to build a csv file with the following structure:

columns [content]            [category]

row1    [Content of file1]   [folder 1]

row2    [Content of file2]   [folder 1]

row3    [Content of file3]   [folder 2]

So the categories are the number of folders, while the content will be the text read from each file.

I tried to do it without the panda df by writing this code:

```
path = r'path/to/main_folder/'
folder = os.listdir(path)

for file in folder:
    print (file)
    with open(path + file, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
        content = f.read()
        category = "1"
        print (content+";"+category)
        with open (r'path/to/main_folder/1/all.txt', "a", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as written:
            written.write(content +";"+ category +'\n')
```

However it created a csv file where rows are the lines from all files, and what I actually want it to do is to create one row per file.
So that each row contains the whole text for a file.

I wrote the general idea:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Content', 'Category']) 

# print dataframe. 
df


path = r'path/to/main_folder/'
folder = os.listdir(path)

# List with the 2 categories
list_categories = [1,2]

for category in list_categories:
    print (category)
    # 1

    category_folder = path + str(category) + '/'
    print (category_folder)
    # r'path/to/main_folder/1' for category 1 

    folder = os.listdir(category_folder)
    for file in folder:
        print (file)

        with open(category_folder + file, 'r') as f:
            df['category'] = category
            df['Content'] = f.read()
```

I'm strugling with the concept of writing to columns and rows in dataframe.
Also, df['category'] = category shows an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

any help in implementing this idea using df the right way?

Comment: Can you post sample files? I guess these files are all a single line so that each forms a single row... and that there is some sort of separator in there to denote columns? Also how are they named? Does the order of rows matter or can the file-to-row conversion be in any order?

Comment: Instead of jumping straight to Pandas, you could try writing to the file using the csv module.